# Failed to convert from a String to a TimeSpan error

Tags: c#, sql

I am attempting to post to my Database using a SqlCommand like so

```
 queryLogResults.Parameters.Add("@executionTime", SqlDbType.Time).Value = executionTime;
```

This is the string I am passing in as executionTime

```
string performanceTime = _stopWatch.Elapsed.ToString("mm':'ss':'fff");
```

I am assuming it has something to do with the milleseconds because it works only sometimes, and if I post just minutes and seconds it works every time. Am I not using the right type of SqlDbType? In my Database ExecutionTime is a time(7) value.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/date-and-time-data suggests using `TimeSpan` - why do you want to use `string` instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're trying to set a parameter value that's of type `SqlDbType.Time`, then you shouldn't need to convert it to a string. Just use

```
TimeSpan performanceTime = _stopWatch.Elapsed;
queryLogResults.Parameters.Add("@executionTime", SqlDbType.Time).Value = performanceTime;
```

Comment: This solution worked fine for me.. seems like I was trying to do to much where the Elapsed time was what I needed. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Looks to me like it's the single quotes in format string:

```
mm':'ss':'fff
```

Additionally, you need to include **Hours** as part of the string. Finally, milliseconds are traditionally separated with a decimal point, rather than a colon.

So a better format string looks like this:

```
HH:mm:ss.fff
```

Since ADO.Net wants to convert this string value back into a `TimeSpan`, it needs to be able to the parse the string, and those formatting differences are throwing it off.

Moreover, since ADO.Net will already use a `TimeSpan` value, I suggest changing the type of the method argument from `string` to `TimeSpan`. Then you can pass `_stopWatch.Elapsed` to the method without converting to a string.

This will also improve performance. Because of the complexity and variety of localization/culture options, converting Date and numeric values to and from strings is surprisingly expensive. You can save your computer some work by avoiding the two conversions in this code.

Comment: I removed the quotes and tried and its now arguing about the string format. I dont think its the single quotes because it works occasionally. I think it has something to do with the milliseconds going over 60

Comment: @Tree55Topz Looking again, you should also include **Hours** in your string, even if they will always be zero. Added this to the answer.